# How to separate specific elements in string java

Tags: java, string, arraylist, delimiter

Example of what I want to do:
If you pass in `"abc|xyz"` as the first argument and `"|"` as the second argument the method returns `List("abc","xyz")`

```
public List<String> splitIt(String string, String delimiter){
        //create and init arraylist.
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        //create and init newString.
        String newString="";
        //add string to arraylist 'list'.
        list.add(string);
        //loops through string.
        for(int i=0;i<string.length();i++){
            //stores each character from string in newString.
            newString += string.charAt(i);              
            }
        newString.replace(delimiter, "");
        //remove string from arraylist 'list'.
        list.remove(string);
        //add newString to arraylist 'list'.
        list.add(newString);
        return list;
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? Can you use [`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `split` method:

```
return Arrays.asList(string.split("\\|"));
```

The two backslashes are there because `split` accepts a **regex**, and `|` is a special character in regexes. Also, backslash is a special character in Java strings. So the first backslash escapes the second one, which escapes the `|`.

`Arrays.asList` will convert the array returned by `split` to a list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this using characters...

1. Get the whole string
2. Read character by character into a new string
3. If you find the delimiter, add new string to list. Empty new string.
4. Repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for ??There is a predefined function in String class.Make use of it

```
 String original ="abc|xyz";
 String[] resulted =original.split("\\|");//returns a String array
```

Play with the `resulted` array here.

Good luck.