# Splitting string at specified point

Tags: java, string, arraylist, split, delimiter

so the method takes two parameters, first is the String you will be splitting, second is the delimiter(where to split at). 
So if I pass in "abc|def" as the first parameter and "|" as the second I should get a List that returns "abc, def" the problem I'm having is that my if statement requires the delimiter is in the current string to be accessed. I can't think of a better condition, any help?

```
public List<String> splitIt(String string, String delimiter){
    //create and init arraylist.
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    //create and init newString.
    String newString="";
    //add string to arraylist 'list'.
    list.add(string);
    //loops through string.
    for(int i=0;i<string.length();i++){
        newString += string.charAt(i);
        if(newString.contains(delimiter)){
            //list.remove(string);
            list.add(newString.replace(delimiter, ""));
            newString="";
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: When posting questions at SO, please have the basic courtesy of indenting them properly (note: TAB chars don't work right), and using the preview to verify that your question is formatted ok.

Comment: Use `indexOf` to find your delimiter in the `String` if it is more than a single character.

Comment: How is this question different than your [previous one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461337/how-to-separate-specific-elements-in-string-java), beside removing `list.remove(string);` and `list.add(newString);` in current code? Also how about using `string.indexOf(delimiter)` to determine if string contains delimiter, and `string.substring(start,end)` to get interesting parts?

Answer (score 1):

Badshaah and cmvaxter code for split using builtin function split(regex) won't work. as you pass "|" as a delimiter "sam|ple" it wont be splitted as [sam,ple] because ( | , + , * , ...) are all used in regex for other purposes.

and u can check character by character, if the delimiter is a character

```
loop(each char)
   if(not delim)
       append to list[i]
   else
       increment i, discard char
```

learning purpose it might be needed in c or c++ (even they 've strtok to split strings) to improve effeciency or to modify something differently. [may split differently not using regex]

Its best to use existing system libraries and functions.

if u want to use your function do something like

> write these functions yourself

```
findpos(delim) // gives position of delimiter found in string
substring(pos,len) //len:size of delimiter
getlist(String str,String delim)
    //for each delim found use substring and append to list
```

**use some pattern matching algorithms like KMP or something u know.**

Comment: Updated mine to escape the |.  Good catch...

Answer (score 0):

The `String` class already supports a `split` method that I believe does exactly what you are looking to do.

```
  String[] s = "abc|def".split("\\|");
  List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s);
```

If you want to do it yourself, the code might look something like this:

```
  char delim = "|".charAt(0);    
  String s = "abc|def|ghi";
  char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  for(char c: chars){
    if (c == delim){
      list.add(sb.toString());
      sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
    else{
      sb.append(c);
    }
  }
  if (sb.length() > 0) list.add(sb.toString());
  System.out.println(list);
```

Comment: Returns a `String[]` whose elements you can shove in a `List`.

Comment: I'm doing this for the benefit of learning, I don't want to use the built in split method, thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

Change your  whole  method to.

```
public List<String> splitIt(String string, String delimiter){
    String[] out = string.split(delimiter);
      return Arrays.asList(out);
   }
```

Comment: I'm doing this for the benefit of learning, I don't want to use the built in split method, thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

Since you are iterating through the string, your if should be based on the character you are inspecting, instead of invoking contains each time:

```
public List<String> splitIt(String string, String delimiter){
    //create and init arraylist.
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    //create and init newString.
    String newString="";
    //add string to arraylist 'list'.
    list.add(string);
    //loops through string.
    int lastDelimiter = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<string.length(); i++) {
        if (delimiter.equals("" + string.charAt(i))) {
            list.add(string.substring(lastDelimiter, i));
            lastDelimiter = i + 1;
        }
    }
    if (lastDelimiter != string.length())
        list.add(string.substring(lastDelimiter, string.length()));

    return list;
}
```

For the sake of learning, I think your original attempt lends itself to a recursive solution.  The general idea in this case would be:

1. If there are no delimiters in the string and it is not empty, return the string as the only element in a new list
2. Otherwise

   1. find the first occurrence of the delimiter
   2. extract the string from the beginning up to the delimiter, call it 'found'
   3. remove the delimiter
   4. recursively call this method, passing it the remainder of the string and the delimiter
   5. append 'found' to the list returned from #4, and return that list